# Passing default arguments to file in Windows

Tags: windows-explorer

Is there any way in Windows explorer to specify arguments which will be added whenever opening a file? I didn't see anything that seemed relevant in Properties...

Comment: Can you not use the command line?

Comment: I just want to be able to double-click the file so that it opens with those arguments. I know I can write a batch script but wondering if there was another way.